# how to echo my data from database using type="radio" with class="btn-check"?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

```
<?php foreach($isi as $u){ ?>

<div>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="status_pendaftaran" value="1" <?php echo $u->status_pendaftaran=="1" ? 'checked' : ''; ?> id="buka" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="status_pendaftaran">Pendaftaran dibuka</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="status_pendaftaran" value="2" <?php echo $u->status_pendaftaran=="2" ? 'checked' : ''; ?> id="tutup" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="status_pendaftaran">Pendaftaran ditutup</label>
</div>

<?php }?>
```

The problem with my code is that I can't switch the button from `value="1"` to `value="2"`.

If the value on database is 1, it will get stuck on `value="1"`. I can't switch it to `value"2"`.

The radio buttons don't let me do it. It's stuck and prevents me to update my database to `value="2"` using the button on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more information about the available field and front end and backend code. However, try something like this. It should give you an idea of what to do.

```
<?php foreach($isi as $u){ ?>

<div>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="status_pendaftaran" value="<?php echo $u->status_pendaftaran ?>" <?php echo $u->status_pendaftaran=="1" ? 'checked' : ''; ?> id="buka" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="status_pendaftaran"><?php echo $u->pendaftaran ?></label>
    
</div>

<?php }?>
```